# Is it possible to change my on-slab heating from Controlled Load to TOU tariff?

Tags: electrical

I have a house that came with in-slab heating. It was previously using Controlled Load circuit to power.

I had never really used it because it was quite expensive to operate - however, I'm about to get solar panels so I figure it might be good to utilise during the day time.

Only problem is the Controlled Load circuit only operates in off peak night (overnight). Is it possible to switch the circuit from the Controlled Load circuit to the normal circuit so I can take advantage of the solar panels?

Is this a job that would require an electrician?

Comment: how does it knows it is night

Comment: @Ruskes some power companies use meters that get a grid time signal so they record energy use per time of day - especially relevant for business use where the rate can change  for high use times like 8-12 etc

Comment: This will depend on the setup in your area, contact an electrician or the power company.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is it ***possible*** - almost certainly.
2. Do you need an electrician? Perhaps, perhaps not. Depends on both you, (how comfortable/competent you are working on electrical circuits) and how the Controlled Load rate connection is implemented physically (may involve needing to relocate things that are in "Licensed Electrician Required" territory.)

Depending on your power company and rate structure, you may want to have the controlled load meter completely removed if there's an extra monthly charge merely for having it there, if you're not using it.

Comment: May also depend on the locale of the OP. Some places allow homeowners to do electrical work on their own properties, some don't.

Comment: That's broadly under point 2, if "anywhere in your house" is "Licensed Electrician Required" territory.

Comment: I didn't really catch that when I first read it (still don't, TBH), so I tried to make it more explicit.

Comment: *if there's an extra monthly charge merely for having it there* Might be the exact opposite! It might be that the utility pays the customer for a guarantee that the large load won't run in peak times.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Don't pay retail to run resistive electric heat. Talk to your utility about a favorable tariff that will make the electric heat make sense - that's what the previous owner did.   Some tariffs are *ridiculous* - you could be paying as little as a penny a kWH to run that heat.

### What is Demand Side Management?

Electricity use is *very peaky* and may increase by a factor of 3 from dead times (5 AM) to afternoon peaks (6 PM) in the summer, and is worse summer vs winter.  This requires huge "PEAKER" generators that run only a few hundred hours per year, but owe a mortgage all year :)  Wind and solar *complicate* things (solar generation tends to precede A/C use by a few hours, because nobody watches *[Technology Connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI)* :), and hydroelectric and batteries *help, a lot*.

Traditional grid design required grid operators to have capacity ready for any consumer load you might turn on.  That's costly, so we're taking *baby steps* toward Demand Side Management. Rest assured, rolling blackouts were "kindergarten mode". 1st grade mode was add hardware to people's houses to let the utility remotely sever people's A/C when they wanted it the most. 2nd grade was cutting loads which were already storage loads, like tanked water heaters or slab heaters. People get mad about demand side management, but as we say to any second grader, it gets better :)

Anyway. You are (should be) being paid to participate in Demand Side Management, by way of getting a favorable electric rate *conditional that they can interrupt it on-demand*. If you rig it to power it from utility anyway, you'll be in breach of contract.  So don't do *that*.  So that said...

### The switching is simple enough... powering not so much.

From a technical perspective, you can have a *DPDT contactor* which (while energized) connects your slab to utility, and while not energized, connects your slab to *something else*.  This contactor can be energized *by utility power* so presence of utility power pre-empts the other supply.

Here is the problem.  Too many people think "solar is magic" and can power any arbitrary load of their choosing *without assist from batteries*. Mmeeeeeeeeh.  Not really.  It doesn't work 1/10 as well as people want it to.

So the sticky part is telling the slab heat to take *only solar power*.  If the slab load is significantly smaller than your solar output, it's pretty straightforward - put CT clamp meters on your solar supply wires, and have some load-shed equipment switch on the slab heat when solar output exceeds the draw of the slab heat.  However, if solar output is often too little to power the entire slab, the heat will rarely run.  You can say "well OK if solar is covering 70% I'll buy the other 30% from the utility" - just adjust the load-shed equipment accordingly *but at this point you're in breach of contract, remember*.

So if your solar is less than the slab needs, but you still want to put it into the slab, good news and bad news.  The good news is that the slab heat is probably a resistive heater.   The better news is that "off-grid" solar systems have a pair of terminals called "DUMP", where it directs surplus solar that can't fit in the battery. This is typically connected to a tank water heater, but slab heat would be *perfect*.   The bad news is this "off-grid style" solar system does not integrate well with "grid-tie" solar system, which I gather is what you have .

However if you never want to sell energy to the utility, ever, you could contemplate an off-grid arrangement. Note that solar financing is *complicated*, and if there is a contract of some kind on that system, you may be constrained as to what you can do with it.

Comment: It's likely that the solar power system will generate much more electricity than we'll need. We decided to oversize to future proof as we expect to get an EV and/or battery in the future. The problem with hooking up the inverter to push the excess energy to the in slab heating is that whilst this'll be good in winter, probably won't make sense in summer. In summer, probably be worth selling excess back to the grid (even at the dismal prices). I was just going to run a timer on the thermostat to only turn on during the day time.

Comment: @SimpleTim Right, they pay less for solar than they charge you for power.  And people see the opportunity to use *storage loads* like HVAC and water heater as a cheap "thermal battery".  Unfortunately, the problem of making your storage loads **exactly match** solar generation *is a hard problem*.   Everyone wants it to be easy.  It's not.